# Speeding up copying from another sheet in VBA using advanced filter

Tags: excel, vba, copy, advanced-filter

I'm very new to VBA and this community so I hope I'm not asking any stupid question and I apologize beforehand if the phrasing of my question isn't up to the standards.

I've been working on a code with the intention of going through a column and copying values from a column in a second sheet to an empty column in my main sheet based on a criteria, but I'm having a bit of a problem with the speed of this code since it takes a long time for me to see the results (sometimes it even crashes depending on the size of the data)
Here's the concerning part of the code :

```
Dim x1 As Integer
Worksheets("A").Activate
x1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
'Add a column in the end to put the add data
Worksheets("A").Cells(1, x1 + 1) = "added data"
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim N1 As Integer
Dim N2 As Integer
N1 = Worksheets("A").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
N2 = Worksheets("B").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To N1
    For j = 2 To N2
        If Worksheets("B").Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("A").Cells(i, 3).Value Then

        Worksheets("A").Cells(i, x1 + 1).Value = Worksheets("B").Cells(j, 3).Value

        GoTo NextIteration

        Else

        End If

   NextIteration:

   Next j

 Next i
```

As you can see, i already tried the GoTo NextIteration method which significantly reduced the time needed to execute the code, but I was wondering if there is a better/faster method to do this especially after learning about the speed of the AdvancedFilter function in VBA.

Also, please feel free to give me any instruction or advice even if it's not related to the main issue.

Have a lovely evening.

Comment: Using the `Find` method would be more efficient.

Comment: Your code is trying to do what the VLOOKUP worksheet formula is meant for. Here you would put VLOOKUP formulas under "added data". Example: =VLOOKUP(C2,B!$A$1:$C$4,3,FALSE)

Comment: I'll try both Find and VLOOKUP methods, great thanks

Comment: Be aware that you are declaring N1 and N2 as integers.  There are over 1 million rows and the max integer is 32,767.  You will want to get used to using Long to avoid errors.  Same goes for i and j.  That may be what “crashing depending on the size of the data” means.

Comment: @DarrellH Thank you so much, i'll make sure to remember to set the iteration's indexes as Long from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, VLOOKUP may be your friend here. If, for some reason, you must *programmatically* append the "added data" column, here is a code example.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim wsA As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim usedRngA As Excel.Range
    Dim formulasRange As Excel.Range
    Dim targetColIndex As Long
    Dim targetLastRowIndex As Long
    Dim sourceLastRowIndex As Long
    Dim lookupFormula As String
    
    Set wsA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A")
    Set usedRngA = wsA.UsedRange
    
    'Column header.
    targetColIndex = usedRngA.Columns.Count + 1
    wsA.Cells(1, targetColIndex).Value = "added data"
    
    'Formulas.
    targetLastRowIndex = usedRngA.Rows.Count
    sourceLastRowIndex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'Check if we have anything to work with.
    If targetLastRowIndex > 1 And sourceLastRowIndex > 1 Then
        lookupFormula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,B!$A$2:$C$" & sourceLastRowIndex & ",3,FALSE), ""Not Found"")"
        Set formulasRange = wsA.Range(wsA.Cells(2, targetColIndex), wsA.Cells(targetLastRowIndex, targetColIndex))
        formulasRange.Formula = lookupFormula
    End If
    
    'If desired, eliminate formulas.
    formulasRange.Value = formulasRange.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the code is fast and it runs so smoothly.
What i'm noticing is that whenever we don't have a match, we are faced with a #N/A error. Is there a way to get Vlookup to return a blank in case we don't have a match without having to loop through the column and replacing #N/A by "" ?

Comment: And what if we had something that we want to replace the #N\A with instead of just going with the empty cell ?

Comment: I just added a call to IFERROR in the formula. If my answer helped, thanks for marking/upvoting it.